# usage of progress bar in SWT in java

Tags: java, swt

Actually i am using threads to update progress bar inside a block of code ,The run method of the thread is not working,So,could you please help me resolve the problem.I am using SWT toolkit for the UI.
        CODE:

//selection listener

```
    tItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
                        {
             TableItem[] tableItems =table.getItems();
                        int c=0;
                int inty=table.getSelectionIndex();
                  for(int i=table.getSelectionIndex();i<tableItems.length;i‌++)
                   {    
                        if(c==0)
                        {
                          column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);       
     //reading content from the table        Stringline=tableItems[i].getText(0)+","+tableItems[i].getTex‌t(1)+","+tableItems[‌​i].getText(2)+","+ta‌​bleItems[i].getText(‌​3)+","+tableItems[i]‌​.getText(4)+","+tabl‌​eItems[i].getText(5)‌​+","+tableItems[i].g‌​etText(6);
                         System.out.println("\n line value is "+line);
                        String split= ",";
                        String error=",,,,,,";
                        if(line.equals(error))
                        {
                        break;
                        }
                    else {while ((line!= null))
                    String[]com = line.split(split,20);
                    String result =null;
//checking whether the value in it is enable or n
                    if(com[0].contains("ENABLE"))
                    { result = "RESULTS"; 
                    continue;}
                    if(com[0].equals("N"))
                    {result = "No";} 
                    else if(com[2].startsWith("S=") )
                    {
                     String O=tableItems[i].getText(7);
                     String[] part = O.split("=");
                     String string2 = part[1];
                     a=Integer.parseInt(string2);
    //declaration of the thread
                     final Thread thread = new Thread()
                    {public void run() 
                    {for(int i=0; i<=a; i++) 
                    {
                    final int value = i;
                    try {
                    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(newRunnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                    { 
    //assigning value to the progress bar
    pbar.setSelection(value);
                    }
                    });
                    }   
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                    System.out.println("Warning");
                     } 
                    } 
                    }
                    thread.start(); 
                    inty++;
                    break;
                    }
    }
    });
```

Comment: swingworker/ separate thread.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer SwingWorker is for Swing **not** SWT

Comment: It sounds like you are running the code in the User Interface thread - you can't do this as it will block the UI. Long running code must be in a separate thread. Show us a [mcve]

Comment: final Thread thread = new Thread(){
                        public void run() {
                        for(int i=0; i<=a; i++) {
                       final int value = i;
                        try {
                         pbar.setSelection(value);
                        } catch (Exception e) { } 
                       }
                        }
                      };
                      thread.start();

Comment: There isn't actually any point in using a Thread here because you aren't running anything that takes a long time. Also the loop setting the progress bar selection isn't going to do anything except set the selection to the last value - you won't get any animation or anything like that.

Comment: if i wont use thread concept over here it won't update dynamically after reading each statement..so i want to use threads..could you please help me in that